# Create a configuration profile MacOS?

Tags: macos-catalina

I am looking to create configuration profiles to standardize settings on Mac computers.

In MacOS user guide, there is a section about how to "Install a configuration profile you’ve received"

I can't find documentation on how to create a configuration profile. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Most MDM's (including Apple's) offer a way to create the configuration profiles for both macOS and iOS. If you want to do this outside of an MDM solution, your best bet is to use ProfileCreator.
https://github.com/ProfileCreator/ProfileCreator

To be honest, I have an MDM solution that offers this feature, but the profiles created with ProfileCreator are better, so I still use it form many profiles and then install them manually or upload them to our server.